# Class constructor called multiple times

Tags: javascript

I have my own Google Maps class that deals with few things like calculating a distance etc. Its code looks like following:

```
class Map{
    constructor(options){
        this.mapcenter = [options.lat, options.lng];
    }
    ...other functions
}
```

in my main JavaScript file I call this after onload:

```
 $(window).on("load", function() {
    if($("#map").length > 0) {
        themap = new Map({
            lat : 46,
            lng : 7
        });
    }
});
```

It has been working for many months but today I got an error `cannot read property lat of undefined`, which is very strange.

Apparently one call onload calls the constructor three times, the second and third being without the options that are in the definition of the call.

I couldn't find anything similar and I believe it's not related to Google Maps API but rather something in the logic I'm missing.

Comment: try using a  different name for you class, there's already a [new Map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Comment: Use a debugger to break on the exception and check the stack trace to see from where exactly it is getting called. The code you have shown in your question *always* passes an object to `new Map`.

Comment: @Taki geez I feel stupid :D They must have added class with identical name (I know I probably should have name it better in the first place) and they were calling mine. Thanks!

Comment: If this "answers your own question," Moeleyi, please go ahead and _"answer_ your own question" so that people who encounter it later will quickly know that it has been answered and what that answer is.

Comment: @Taki do you want to put it as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use a diffrenet name for your Class, there's already a built-in [new Map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Comment: It should still work if the `class Map` is declared in a local scope (where the builtin `Map` is not needed). If it is assigned to the global `Map` variable, the code should still continue to work without any changes, but no other code (including libraries) would be able to use the builtin.